# Cannot use NodaTime's Instant.InZone with the DateTimeZone in a variable with Npgsql's Entity Framework Core provider

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql, nodatime, ef-core-6.0

So I'm running into a rather odd issue here. I've got a PostgreSQL 14 server and I'm using the Npgsql Entity Framework Core provider to access it. If I have an Entity Framework Core entity that contains a date as a NodaTime `Instant` type (which becomes `timestamp with time zone` in the database) and try to project that via `.InZone(timeZone).LocalDateTime`, I run into 3 situations.

Actual example query would be something like this:

```
await context.Entities.Select(e => e.Date.InZone(<timeZone>).LocalDateTime).ToListAsync();
```

(Although it seems that not including the `.LocalDateTime` portion has no bearing on the below situations, with the exception of when `.InZone(<timeZone>)` is replaced with `.InUtc()`.)

The first situation, if in place of `<timeZone>` I make an explicit call to `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault()`, then the above query succeeds without issue. (Although oddly, when I look at EFCore's generated SQL, I do not see `AT TIME ZONE` like the Npgsql docs mention, but I do see it if I was to replace the `.InZone(<timeZone>)` call with `.InUtc()`.)

The second situation, if in place of `<timeZone>` I put in a reference to a static variable containing the result of `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault()`, then I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the following message:

```
The client projection contains a reference to a constant expression of 'NodaTime.TimeZones.CachedDateTimeZone' which is being passed as an argument to the method 'InZone'. This could potentially cause a memory leak; consider assigning this constant to a local variable and using the variable in the query instead. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2103067 for more information.
```

Given the above, I run into the third situation, if in place of `<timeZone>` I use a local variable that contains either the result of `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault()` or the static variable I mentioned above, then I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the following message:

```
Expression '@__timeZone_0' in the SQL tree does not have a type mapping assigned.
```

Am I doing something wrong here? My expected goal is to be able to take the `Instant` that I'd get from the database's `timestamp with time zone` and have it be either a `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDateTime` on the client end, without needing to go through extra steps on the client end after obtaining the data from the database. Right now I would have to get the date from the database using `.InUtc().LocalDateTime` and then after the list has been materialized, I'd be able to do conversions on the returned values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NodaTime plugin doesn't support passing parameterized time zones from .NET; you can only use a constant expression such as `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/Berlin"]` ([see these docs](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/nodatime.html#operation-translation) for supported translations). You can use this to convert a PG `timestamp with time zone` into a `timestamp without time zone` in PG, and then retrieve the result as a `timestamp without time zone`, which can be read as a NodaTime LocalDateTime.

However, if what you're looking for is to get a ZonedDateTime/LocalDateTime with the time zone of the client machine (where .NET is executing), then doing `.InUtc().LocalDateTime` is the way to do that - any reason you're trying to avoid it?

A bit more context (as well as a full code sample) could shed some more light on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't really have a full code sample, but mainly I wanted to display the UTC time I obtain from the database in the user's time zone (our's in this case is America/New_York). While I can definitely use `.InUtc().LocalDateTime` to grab the date from the database, it would still be in UTC and I'd have to do take that LocalDateTime value after I have it from the database and use `.InUtc().WithZone(<timeZone>)` to get it in the user's time zone. I mainly wanted to have this done via the EFCore projection instead of afterwards.

Comment: But what is the user's time zone stored (America/New_York)? In the above sample you're discussing GetSystemDefault(), which is the machine time zone - is that what you're referring to as the "user's time zone"? Because in most applications, different users have different time zones, based on where they are, and the machine's time zone (where your server happens to be located) shouldn't have any bearing on anything.

Comment: Even if you're interested in the machine time zone, is it the machine where the .NET application is running, or where PG is running?

Answer (score 0):

There is a hacky way around this. As user Shay Rojansky mentioned, you cannot pass the DateTimeZone variable, however, you can pass a string containing the Id of the timezone.

```
var timezone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault();
                
var timezoneName = timezone.Id;

await context.Entities.Select(e => e.Date.InZone(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timezoneName]).LocalDateTime).ToListAsync();
```